# Cannot handle error thrown in the JWTStrategy callback

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I have setup JwtStrategy for authentication my api endpoints. And as you can see I throw custom `JWTExpired` error if `jwtPayload.expires > Date.now()`, if you console error on the catch block , it will, then the code will throw same error again and crash the app. I have used the same structure with `LocalStrategy` to throw custom `PasswordNotMatch` error and it works there quite well.

```
passport.use(
  new JWTStrategy(
    {
      jwtFromRequest: req => {
        return req.cookies.jwt;
      },
      secretOrKey: secret
    },
    (jwtPayload, done) => {
      try {
        if (jwtPayload.expires > Date.now()) {
          return done(null, jwtPayload);
        } else {
          throw new JWTExpired();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. I was not handling routing errors, so as JWT expired it was the passport.js that was re-throwing the error I passed with `done(error)`;